# How to extract table from a webpage

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been trying to extract the table from a webpage.
I don't know what to do next here is what I wrote.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page= requests.get('http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/nmdc/ratios/NMD02')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(class_='tabns MR10')
```

and now I don't know what to do. I can't find table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class tabns and MR10 do not refer to a table on the page you are trying to get.  That class combination refers to a div that contains an unordered list which lays out the tabs on the top of the tables.  Class .det looks like it will get your table, but without knowing what you are trying to scrape I can't be sure.

try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page= requests.get('http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/nmdc/ratios/NMD02')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.findAll(class_='det')

for node in table:
    if 'colspan' in node.attrs:
        if len(node.contents) == 1:
            print('')
            print(node.contents[0].ljust(48), end="")

    elif len(node.contents) == 1:
        print(node.contents[0].ljust(10), end="")
```

This is what I got from that code:

```
Face Value                                      1.00      1.00      1.00          1.00      1.00      
Dividend Per Share                              5.15      11.00     8.55      8.50      7.00      
Operating Profit Per Share (Rs)                 11.38     8.04      19.62     19.61     18.60     
Net Operating Profit Per Share (Rs)             27.90     16.28     31.17     30.41     27.00     
Free Reserves Per Share (Rs)                    --        --        --        --        --        
Bonus in Equity Capital                         83.53     66.66     66.66     66.66     66.66     
Operating Profit Margin(%)                      40.79     49.40     --        64.46     68.89     
Profit Before Interest And Tax Margin(%)        34.97     36.23     --        53.86     55.91     
Gross Profit Margin(%)                          38.57     46.18     --        63.21     67.60     
Cash Profit Margin(%)                           28.61     41.57     --        46.11     50.05     
Adjusted Cash Margin(%)                         28.61     41.57     45.80     46.11     50.05     
Net Profit Margin(%)                            29.32     46.90     51.97     53.24     59.25     
Adjusted Net Profit Margin(%)                   26.59     36.79     --        45.36     49.00     
Return On Capital Employed(%)                   19.15     15.04     --        32.40     34.44     
Return On Net Worth(%)                          11.49     10.05     --        21.40     23.05     
Adjusted Return on Net Worth(%)                 11.49     10.67     20.21     21.26     23.04      
Return on Assets Excluding Revaluations         71.17     75.95     81.55     75.64     69.39     
Return on Assets Including Revaluations         71.17     75.95     81.55     75.64     69.39     
Return on Long Term Funds(%)                    19.15     15.79     30.56     32.40     34.44     
Current Ratio                                   3.52      4.44      11.63     16.52     7.73      
Quick Ratio                                     3.20      11.73     11.31     16.06     7.54      
Debt Equity Ratio                               --        0.05      --        --        --        
Long Term Debt Equity Ratio                     --        --        --        --        --        
Interest Cover                                  207.82    72.68     --        5,252.61  717.84    
Total Debt to Owners Fund                       --        0.05      --        --        --        
Financial Charges Coverage Ratio                217.27    75.86     --        5,333.91  728.34    
Financial Charges Coverage Ratio Post Tax       135.17    50.45     --        3,552.62  491.98    
Inventory Turnover Ratio                        16.35     10.14     --        17.71     16.81     
Debtors Turnover Ratio                          6.01      3.54      7.72      9.53      11.77     
Investments Turnover Ratio                      16.35     10.14     17.87     17.71     16.81     
Fixed Assets Turnover Ratio                     4.26      1.96      --        4.66      4.46      
Total Assets Turnover Ratio                     0.84      0.30      --        0.40      0.39      
Asset Turnover Ratio                            0.54      0.24      0.40      0.42      0.41      
Average Raw Material Holding                    --        --        --        --        --        
Average Finished Goods Held                     --        --        --        --        --        
Number of Days In Working Capital               156.37    1,054.96  644.26    680.29    752.56    
Material Cost Composition                       3.05      4.52      2.81      3.09      2.69      
Imported Composition of Raw Materials Consumed  --        --        --        --        --        
Selling Distribution Cost Composition           0.08      0.23      --        --        --        
Expenses as Composition of Total Sales          --        --        --        --        --        
Dividend Payout Ratio Net Profit                50.71     144.01    52.78     52.49     43.75     
Dividend Payout Ratio Cash Profit               47.14     134.76    51.48     51.29     42.82     
Earning Retention Ratio                         49.30     -35.71    48.14     47.15     56.23     
Cash Earning Retention Ratio                    52.87     -27.46    49.39     48.37     57.17     
AdjustedCash Flow Times                         --        0.44      --        --        --
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pyquery](https://github.com/gawel/pyquery) easily.

```
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
page = requests.get('http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/nmdc/ratios/NMD02')
html = pq(page.content)
rows = html(".table4:last tr")
for tr in rows:
    # tr.find("td")
    # pq(tr)("td")
    print tr
```

Comment: <Element tr at 0x7f2a54ce5fc8>
<Element tr at 0x7f2a54d23208>
<Element tr at 0x7f2a54d23050>
<Element tr at 0x7f2a54d230a8>
<Element tr at 0x7f2a54d23100>
<Element tr at 0x7f2a54d23158>

I am getting this after using this code how to save this thing in a table or text format?